# Adding two label values and then inserting the result in a table

Tags: asp.net, sql

I want to add two values that are stored in two labels(mostly decimal values) and then insert it into a table using sqlcommmand.Here is my code:

```
      protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double balance;
    double reward;
    Session["FinalBalance"] = (double.TryParse(lblBalance.Text, out balance) + (double.TryParse(lblReward.Text, out reward)).ToString());
    lblFinal.Text = Session["FinalBalance"].ToString();
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABCD"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tblRegister('Balance') values('@FinalBalance')", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinalBalance", Session["FinalBalance"].ToString());
    }


}
```

Now what happens is,it doesnt insert the sum into the table.So i checked the sum by passing its value to a label and its gives out 'TrueTrue'.I guess it is giving out boolean results.How do i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You should check on double values using double.TryParse first, then if it's true then the value is double, if not, then set the value to 0.

The following should work:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
          double balance;
          bool isDouble = double.TryParse(lblBalance.Text, out balance);
          if(!isDouble)
          {
              balance = 0;
          }

          double reward;
          bool isDouble2 = double.TryParse(lblReward.Text, out reward);
          if(!isDouble2)
          {
              reward=0;
          }

          Session["FinalBalance"] = balance + reward;

          lblFinal.Text = Session["FinalBalance"].ToString();
          string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABCD"].ConnectionString;
          using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
          {
              con.Open();
              SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tblRegister('Balance') values('@FinalBalance')", con);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinalBalance", Session["FinalBalance"].ToString());
          }
}
```

Comment: and then simply add balance and reward?

Comment: yes, and in case you wanted both values must be double, you can just try onskee solution or modify this one.

Answer (score 0):

`double.TryParse` returns a boolean.  The 'parsed' value is in your balance and reward output variables.

You'll want something like this:

```
if((double.TryParse(lblBalance.Text, out balance) && (double.TryParse(lblReward.Text, out reward))){
    Session["FinalBalance"] = balance + reward;
}
else{
    // some kind of error handling
}
```